# Clear multiple set after hitting the WaitOne() of AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, autoresetevent

Do I need  to call `reset` to clear multiple set after hitting the `WaitOne();` of `AutoResetEvent` in C#?

Comment: I fixed up the title as much as I could, but can you please add some detail to the question? Preferably with some context and example code.

Comment: Thank you RGraham.I just want to know how it behaves. if i set multiple times before hitting the Waitone(), wait one will clear all sets? or the first set will be cleared and all other will remains there in list of sets?

Comment: The word "AutoReset" in the name of the class is a rather strong hint that you don't.  As opposed to ManualResetEvent.  "Multiple set" is almost always a bug generator, pretty likely you ought to be looking at Semaphore or CountdownEvent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AutoResetEvent` does not have a counter - just a set/not-set state, so no, you do not have to do anything special after a `WaitOne()` call returns even if the event was set multiple times.